# Neither eye appears for now,

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I want to show both eyes but don’t appear at this time,
Is there a solution for this , I have a problem with parent, which is currently still dependent on the other, I want the parent to stand alone, without sticking to the other, so that both eyes can appear, so for now the two eyes do not appear as desired,

```
create(): void {
    this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    this.balls = this.generateBalls();    
    this.dance = this.generateDance();

    // this.playerEyes = new Eye(this.generateEyeArg(200,135,3.0));
    this.inputA = this.generateEyeArg( 340, 300, 3.0 );
    this.inputB = this.generateEyeArg( 460, 300, 3.0 );

    this.charactorA = new Eye( this.inputA );
    this.charactorB = new Eye( this.inputB );
    // console.log("gameObject", this.charactorA);

}
generateEyeArg( xCoor: number, yCoor: number, sScale: number) {

    return {
        scene           : this,
        parent          : this,
        target          : new Cursor( this ),   // game.input.mousePointer,
        x               : xCoor,                // x, y position is the location that the eyes 
        y               : yCoor,                // object is originally located within the parent
        width           : 10,                   // height/width is the total area of the eye object (subject to scaling)
        height          : 8,
        w2h             : 0.9,                  // Eye ball width to height ratio
        scale           : sScale,
        eyeSpacing      : 3.5,                    // Distance between eyes
        pupilScale      : 1.0,
        pupilRotRadius  : 0.7,                  // Factor of radius pupils can rotate around eye white
        pupilColor      : 0x0f00ff
    };
}
```

Comment: `this.generateBalls()` this will end up at tumbrl :D

Comment: Can you please provide current output / screenshot and desired project? Also it's not whole code promblem may be inside `generateBalls()`.

Comment: Always be careful when asking about [balls](https://www.lexico.com/definition/balls).

Comment: there is something wrong with this code,
https://github.com/mcferren/sss-phaser/blob/0af41132187b76c8982fdd822bd2d24301b6ba4a/src/games/gewgly/objects/Eye/eye.ts#L18

after I fix it now it has gone well, and a pair of eyes, has performed perfectly. thank you sir @Zydnar, for checking it out,  thanks@Teemu